# did I correctly build my siamese network?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp

I am trying to build my siamese network for finding text-similarity. below is the model.
Want to know whether There are sharing weigths.

```
sub_model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([Embedding(vocab_size,300,input_length=79), 
Bidirectional(LSTM(79,return_sequences=True)),
Bidirectional(LSTM(79,return_sequences=True)),
tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=158)
])
ins1=Input((79,),name='input1')
ins2=Input((79,),name='input2')
sub1=sub_model(ins1)
sub2=sub_model(ins2)
norm1=tf.keras.layers.Layer(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x,axis=1),name='out1')(sub1)
norm2=tf.keras.layers.Layer(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x,axis=1),name='out2')(sub2)
model=Model({'input1':ins1,'input2':ins2},outputs={'out1':norm1,'out2':norm2})
```

when training, gradients are not flowing through the network. I found that by writing custom training loop. the loss function which I wrote is working properly.It is giving the loss value. But gradients are getting 'None' value.
here is the [model_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gu9H.png)

Comment: Can you add the image generated by `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'my_first_model.png', show_shapes=True)`?

Comment: I added the plot

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly built your model. As you can see you have two different inputs of shapes (None,79) and you are passing both of them to the same sequential model.

You have to either merge the inputs by adding another `merge` layer or pass the inputs to separate sequential layers.

I'll show you both the constructions.

Merging:

```
ins1=Input((79,),name='input1')
ins2=Input((79,),name='input2')
merge = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([ins1,ins2])
sub_model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([Embedding(vocab_size,300,input_length=158), 
    Bidirectional(LSTM(79,return_sequences=True)),
    Bidirectional(LSTM(79,return_sequences=True)),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=158)
    ])(merge)
norm1=tf.keras.layers.Layer(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x,axis=1),name='out1')(sub_model)
norm2=tf.keras.layers.Layer(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x,axis=1),name='out2')(sub_model)
model=tf.keras.Model({'input1':ins1,'input2':ins2},outputs={'out1':norm1,'out2':norm2})
```

Your model:

[image: Merged]

Passing through separate sequential blocks:

```
def create_submodel():
    sub_model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([Embedding(vocab_size,300,input_length=79), 
    Bidirectional(LSTM(79,return_sequences=True)),
    Bidirectional(LSTM(79,return_sequences=True)),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=158)
    ])
    return sub_model

ins1=Input((79,),name='input1')
ins2=Input((79,),name='input2')

sub1=create_submodel()(ins1)
sub2=create_submodel()(ins2)
norm1=tf.keras.layers.Layer(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x,axis=1),name='out1')(sub1)
norm2=tf.keras.layers.Layer(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x,axis=1),name='out2')(sub2)
model=tf.keras.Model({'input1':ins1,'input2':ins2},outputs={'out1':norm1,'out2':norm2})
```

Your model:
[image: Seperate blocks]

You can also create something like this:

```
def create_submodel():
    sub_model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([Embedding(vocab_size,300,input_length=79), 
    Bidirectional(LSTM(79,return_sequences=True)),
    Bidirectional(LSTM(79,return_sequences=True)),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=158)
    ])
    return sub_model

ins1=Input((79,),name='input1')
ins2=Input((79,),name='input2')

sub1=create_submodel()(ins1)
sub2=create_submodel()(ins2)
merge = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([sub1,sub2])
norm1=tf.keras.layers.Layer(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x,axis=1),name='out1')(merge)
norm2=tf.keras.layers.Layer(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x,axis=1),name='out2')(merge)
model=tf.keras.Model({'input1':ins1,'input2':ins2},outputs={'out1':norm1,'out2':norm2})
```

Your model:

[image: Combined]

Just make sure that if you are joining two layers to single layers you first merge the outputs and only then pass the merged output to the single layer.